# Adding a integer value to string on a single statement

Tags: string, go, int, type-conversion

I was wondering how can I add an integer value to a string value like "10". I know I can accomplish this by converting the `string` into an `int` first and then after adding the integer I can convert it back into `string`. But can I accomplish this in a single statement in golang. For example I can do this with multiple lines like this:

```
i, err := strconv.Atoi("10")
// handle error
i = i + 5
s := strconv.Itoa(i)
```

But is there any way that I can accomplish this in a single statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no ready function in the standard library for what you want to do. And the reason for that is because adding a number to a number available as a `string` and having the result as another `string` is (terribly) *inefficient*.

The model (memory representation) of the `string` type does not support adding numbers to it efficiently (not to mention that `string` values are immutable, a new one has to be created); the memory model of `int` does support adding efficiently for example (and CPUs also have direct operations for that). No one wants to add `int`s to numbers stored as `string` values. If you want to add numbers, have your numbers ready just as that: numbers. When you want to print or transmit, only then convert it to `string` (if you must).

But everything becomes a single statement if you have a ready util function for it:

```
func add(s string, n int) (string, error) {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return strconv.Itoa(i + n), nil
}
```

Using it:

```
s, err := add("10", 5)
fmt.Println(s, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LnuZFWuY3Z)):

```
15 <nil>
```